# Sake & Samurai / Beer & Vikings: Burning up spirits while being tormented

Tags: sake-and-samurai, beer-and-vikings

The rules for the games [Sake & Samurai](http://www.albepavo.com/SAKE/sake_overview-en.html) and [Beer & Vikings](http://www.albepavo.com/SAKE/beer_overview-en.html) allow dead players to "torment" players that are still living by stealing their Sake/Beer tokens. But any player is always allowed to "Burn up" as many Sake/Beer tokens as he likes to perform special actions.

How should any dead player ever successfully steal a token when the target of the "tormenting" can simply burn up all tokens that might be stolen?

Answer (score 2):

The creators of the game responded to my inquiry:

> Yes, this is possible, but if the target burns every token, he/she loses any chance of winning! So tormenting has to be played "not too aggressively" by Spirits, in order for the target to agree to a little loss - that's usually how we see it played!

Comment: I thought that "burning your entire supply of tokens in response to a torment attempt" was probably cutting off your nose to spite your face, but not having actually played the game I wasn't sure!